# ProxyPass Apache 2.4 simple proxypass not working

Tags: apache-2.4, proxypass, http-proxy

i have the following situation:
i need to call the following url `http://myapp.mydomain.com`

and the url should reply as following
`http://myapp.mydomain.com/index.jsp`

On my apache 2.4
i tryied different setup but none seems to work,

First attempt

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /myapp http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp
    ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp
</VirtualHost>
```

Second attempt

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /myapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverse /myapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
</VirtualHost>
```

Third attempt

```
    <Location "/myapp/">
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
   </Location>
```

Fourth attempt

```
<Location "/myapp/">
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /myapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverse /myapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
```

None of the configuration seem to work,
the url `https://myapp.mydomain.com` brings up the welcome page of the tomcat.
And what ever configuration i apply to apache, the only way to make it work is to manually add on the link the mountpoint of proxy, as following

```
http://myapp:mydomain.com/myapp/index.jsp
```

Any suggestion on how can i make this work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a `ServerName myapp.mydomain.com` inside the VirtualHost. Apache is not able to know that the vhost created is for that dns address.

Answer (score 0):

Use below ProxyPass inside VirtualHost and test.

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
```